# Kniphofia caulescens not flowering

Tags: flowering, perennials

I planted two *Kniphofia caulescens* in a sunny spot in my garden back in 2016. The plants have thrived and now form a sizeable clump. However, they haven't flowered for several years. Any idea why this might be? I live in west Essex, England. The soil is heavyish clay.

Comment: I'd slice into the clump and move some roots to different locations and to pots with lighter soil mix. They like drainage.